# Why does my MongoDB collection returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to use `find()` to display my MongoDB Collection via my Express app, however whenever I run my app my Mongo collection it returns an empty array.

I found answers on here but are using Mongoose for their db connection. I'm able to connect via Mongoose just fine but would like to learn via MongoDB as well.

I created my db via MongoDB compass app, so I don't have a schema file. Below is my code including db connection:

**dbConfig.js** I didn't use async/await functions as it's still a little hard for me to grasp/follow

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
var _db;

module.exports = {
    connectToServer: (callback) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDB', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
            _db = client.db('test');
            console.log('db is connected');
            return callback(err);
        })
    }, 
    getDb: () => {
        return _db;
    }
}
```

**index.js** Here is my app file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongodbConfig = require('./config');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongodbConfig.connectToServer( (err) => {

    const findRouter = require('./find');

    app.use('/find', findRouter);

    app.listen(port, () => console.log('App connected'));
})
```

**findRoute.js** Here is where I'm getting the empty array

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongodbConfig = require('./config');
const db = mongodbConfig.getDb();


router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    db.collection('test').find({}).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.send('That worked');
        console.log('Here are you results:', results);
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

I'm not too sure what I'm missing, is there a more consistent way for incorporating Mongo into your Express app so that it doesn't return an empty array? I would like to keep my db configure/utill file separate if possible.

Comment: You might need to look into node.js concepts, there are couple of issues with the code, if we check on DB thing first, So is your collection name is `test` in db called `test` & has documents already inserted in it?

Comment: My db is ‘TestDB’ with a collection name of ‘test’. I have one document in that collection. What are some issues that I need to fix?

Comment: `res.send('That worked');
        console.log('Here are you results:', results);` & also why is this like this ::  `console.log('db is connected');
            return callback(err);` ??

Comment: I guess i'm just trying to get the results to display via the console and just sent something via the `res` object so that  I wouldn't timeout. And for the `return callback (err)` i had grabbed that from a SO answer that helps with separating the db connection into it's' own file.

Comment: If your db is `"TestDB"` then you need to do `_db = client.db('TestDB');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the case for you but for me alot of times the callback function was the problem. I use mongoose, however it should be similar, and in my case too find would always return null, how i fixed it was with async and await functionality instead of the callback function :

```
var err, results = await TestModel.find();
```

where TestModel is mongoose.Model('test', TestSchema);

Can you give this a try